# HTTP 500 Internal Error after installing SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, error, installation

I'm encountering HTTP 500 Internal Error after installing SharePoint 2010. I ran SharePoint 2010 Central Administration at the first time and got it. I ran IISRESET but there was any changes. Also, I set CallStack="true", CustomErrors="Off" and debug="true" and then got "The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE)) "

Even I configured container in Active Directory in order to track SharePoint 2010 Installation but I did not saw any changes there.

I'm using Vmware to deploy SharePoint with single-server deployment.

I installed SharePoint 2010 twice and have still gotten the error.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: > HTTP 500 Internal Server Error: While opening Central Administration |
> SP 2010 using Windows 7 > > I am having this error while opening Central Administration of SP 2010
> I checked the event viewer got this as the last entry........** Log Name: Microsoft-SharePoint Products-Shared/Operational Source: Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Server Search Date: 14-02-2013 23:35:08 Event ID: 97 Task Category: Admin Audit Level: Information Keywords: User: NETWORK SERVICE Computer: Aman-PC **Description: An incremental crawl was started on 'Local SharePoint sites' by NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SER

Comment: Are there any errors in the application event log?

Answer (score 1):

Thuan,

I ran into this a while back and doing as prescribed in the following thread did the trick for me.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/af64081d-3f90-4515-80c8-55515447854f

Comment: I did Web.Config default and then got HTTP 500 Internal Error too. Thank for your reply but it did not concern exactly my problem.

Comment: I just audited all permission and then recognized that my account, which was used to install SharePoint 2010 binaries, didn't belong to local Administrator group on SharePoint server.

Answer (score 0):

I  just ran into this same problem. I know this is an old question but for people like me that are searching for this I want to post my solution to the problem. I tried a lot of different things to try en resolve this. I noticed that in my IIS, when I highlighted my SharePoint - 80 site and both SharePoint Central Administrator and SharePoint Web Services Sites that there was an ISAPI filter for Framework 4.0. Since SP2010 uses v2.0 I removed those filters and that did the trick.

HTTP 500 could reference to a lot of different things and I remembered that there was an error pointing to the asp v4.0 directory.

Try checking all the settings on your IIS including your ISAPI filters.

Good luck,

Osvaldo